# Postfix - Google Apps for Business - MX Records - DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, postfix, mx-record, g-suite

We are planning a migration away from Google Apps for Business handling our email services. The services worked well to get us out of the gate, but now we need to consider scale, both volume and pricing, so we opted to maintain our own email servers.

My question is, is it possible to co-mingle their MX records with our own? My approach would be to add a new MX record for the domain with a priority of 1, and bump all the current Google MX records down in priority, consider the following:

```
# Current
1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
5 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
5 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
10 ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM    
10 ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM

# Proposed
1 mail.example.com
5 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
10 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
10 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
20 ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM    
20 ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM
```

After we export / import current email accounts I will just remove all google references.

Is this parallel approach possible?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: Not yet, we are still in process of setting up the infrastructure in AWS, once we get everything ported over we will be focusing on email. I will post up when we get there.

Comment: Cool Deal, have you looked at Zimbra's open source system as well or sticky with the basics?

Comment: Basics. A lot of R&D went into ensuring we adhere to all the expected practices such as DKIM, SPF, and DMARC to ensure the highest delivery possible. We may bring in mailgun to handle super high volume, but will deal with that when we get there. What we are trying to avoid is the $5/user fee that Google charges. Doesn't scale well with startups.

Comment: Excellent, don't forget opportunistic TLS on your smtp servers

Comment: Yes, have that as well, with a wildcard cert so we can add as many nodes as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible, no not like that

MX Records are load balancing, the must all accept or deny equally.

What you want is called [dual delivery](https://youtu.be/bqIcWyNzPBA) which is specific to Google apps.

Comment: Thx this looks like the way to go.